# Dynamic object from either from two class in java

Tags: java

UserCourse and NewReleases are different class with same method. but different output.

```
final Object userCourses;

    if(mFlag == 11){
            try{
                userCourses = new UserCourses(params[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.i(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        else if(mFlag == 44){
            try{
                userCourses = new NewReleases();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.i(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Now, when I call

```
userCourses.getUserCourses().get(i);
```

I get "Add cast to userCourses" error.
Both class has this method.

Is it possible to do this or not? If yes please tell me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you expect this to work, `useCourses` is of the base type `Object` - which does not have this method.

Learn about `Interfaces` and how to use them.

Comment: Hey thanks. I have created Interfaces, but don't know it's also used. I will learn and use them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be casting to the actual object that has the method.

Example:

`((UserCourses)userCourses).getUserCourses().get(i);` or

`((NewReleases)userCourses).getUserCourses().get(i);`

`Object` is a generic supertype that all objects are derived from.

That is why you can assign both a `new UserCourses` and a `NewReleases` to `Object`.

But then you would have to downcast to the specific object to be able to call the actual method.

This approach though is bad programming as it is not type safe. 
But this snippet of code can work with this change.

For refactoring the code you should follow another approach. Read about interfaces as @Nim answer